# Incorrect count of filtered rows VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel ws "Monthly Data". I am trying to apply an auto filter (xlFilterLastMonth) and count the number of filtered rows.

```
With Sheets("Monthly Data")                     
    .Range("A1:BB" & lastrow1).AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic

MsgBox ws2.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count

End With
```

Comment: I don't think it will affect the outcome, but you're using "Monthly Data" in your `With` line and referencing `ws2` in the message box.

Comment: If the visible cells are not contiguous, you have to separately count the rows in each `Area`.  (Or you could try the `SubTotal` function as suggested by J.B.)

Comment: @J.B "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: To apply 2 separate filters on 2 separate columns count the number of rows. With Sheets("LifeTimeData") .Range("A1:BB" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlAnd .Range("A1:BB" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="*" & "Deposit", Operator:=xlFilterDynamic Set r = Intersect(.AutoFilter.Range, .Range("A:A")) Filtred_Rows_Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, r) - 1 'Worksheets("LifeTimeData").AutoFilterMode = False 'Sheets("Overview").Range("G16") = Filtred_Rows_Count MsgBox Filtred_Rows_Count En

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on J.B.s answer:

```
With Sheets("Monthly Data")
    .Range("A1:BB" & lastrow1).AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic

    Set r = Intersect(.AutoFilter.Range, .Range("A:A"))
    Filtred_Rows_Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, r) - 1

    MsgBox Filtred_Rows_Count
End With
```

Comment: To apply 2 separate filters on 2 separate columns count the number of rows. With Sheets("LifeTimeData")
    .Range("A1:BB" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlAnd
    .Range("A1:BB" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="*" & "Deposit", Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
    
    Set r = Intersect(.AutoFilter.Range, .Range("A:A"))
    Filtred_Rows_Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, r) - 1
    'Worksheets("LifeTimeData").AutoFilterMode = False
    'Sheets("Overview").Range("G16") = Filtred_Rows_Count
    MsgBox Filtred_Rows_Count
En

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
With Sheets("Monthly Data")
    .Range("A1:BB" & lastrow1).AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic

    Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range, Range("A:A"))
    Filtred_Rows_Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, r) - 1

    MsgBox Filtred_Rows_Count
End With
```

Comment: ws2 is not the active sheet where the data is getting filtered.

Comment: done that. no joy. application defined or object defined error.

Comment: @Tanmoy Then you didn't change it _correctly_ . I'll post an answer

Comment: J.B. - I've posted an answer showing how the ranges should be qualified - if you want to update yours to do the same I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are headers for each column, then try this

```
Dim Data1 As Range, Data2 As Range


Set Data1 = Sheets("Monthly Data").Range("A1:BB" & LastRow1)

Data1.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic

Set Data2 = Range(Cells(2, 21), Cells(LastRow1, 21)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each cell In Data2
    i = i + 1
Next

Worksheets("Monthly Data").AutoFilterMode = False
MsgBox "The number of filtered rows is " & i
```

Comment: @Tanmoy It does work. I try all my code before posting it as an answer. What is your statement for `LastRow1`? I used `LastRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` provided your range of data is a well-formatted data sheet. What I mean by a "well-formatted data sheet", is a worksheet with data that starts in cell A1 and the number of the rows in column A and columns in row 1 must be equal to the range of all data.

Comment: @Tanmoy See this [screenshot of my worksheet](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k4SPS.png). I modified the above code to fit in with the dummy data. Have a look the entire picture. See also in the bottom left corner.